# Remove n chars from end of String

Tags: java, string, integer

Can I somehow remove `n` chars from the end of a String ?

In example:

```
String a = "Hello";
a -= 1;
```

With the result being `a` = `"Hell"` ?

Comment: No. Why would you expect subtracting 1 from "Hello" to subtract the letter o?

Comment: Er ... No! Not even in any other language I know of.

Comment: Use the `substring` method

Comment: I hoped it could just remove the last entry of the String.

Comment: If said `String` contained a number then you could invoke the `parse` method upon it then perform your calculations and then convert back to a string.

Comment: I think he's just chosen an unfortunate way to articulate his question; reason for down-votes?

Comment: I really feel this is something missing from java, you know you also can't divide a Class by 2 or add a Badger to a Fox. Ok i'm sorry its actually a reasonable question just expressed strangely

Comment: In fact a code sample of "how I want it to work" really helps the question make sense. Actually well written with the exception of the "assumed answer", I feel the -1s are unfair so +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = a.substring(0,a.length()-1);
```

See this [String#substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) to understand better:

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

Comment: Elaborate your answer, so newbees can understand what you are saying

Answer (score 2):

Ok, instead of giving you -1, I can help :)
In Java, do

```
String a = "Hello";
int stepsBack = 1;

if (a.length()>=stepsBack) //Avoid StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
    a=a.substring(0,a.length()-stepsBack);

System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. The best you can hope for is something like:

```
a = a.substring(0, a.length() - 1);
```

Or this:

```
a = new StringBuilder(a).deleteCharAt(a.length() - 1).toString();
```

Or even this:

```
a = a.replaceAll(".$", "");
```

Comment: That should be 
  `a = a.substring(0, a.length() - 1);`

Comment: @ZouZou OK. I'm typing this stuff in on my iPhone :/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is definetely not! But you can use `substring` if you want to remove the characters by integer using integer based index. Try this:

```
String a = "Hello";

a = a.substring(0,a.length()-1);

System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't subract from a string, however you can achieve what you want with substring:

```
        String in="hello";
        String out=in.substring(0, 4); //takes the characters 0,1,2,3 from in (i.e. h e l l)

        System.out.println(out);
```